# Jmeter to pass JSF View State in Post request

Tags: jsf-2, jmeter

I am evaluating the JMeter to be used for Load testing of our JSF application.

I followed the below link to find the way to pass JSF View State Id from one requests to other and it worked.
http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/PerformanceTestingWithJMeter

I can see the JSF View State Id getting passed ,but the issue is the String got modified as below and causing view expired exception.

```
Actual JSF View State returned from GET :5843186584364912760:4842974224399060609
  The subsequent POST request send this :5843186584364912760%3A4842974224399060609
```

The ":" character in middle is replaced with %3A (hexa value), is there any way to bypass  this and pass the exact string from one request to other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flag this parameter so that it won't be encoded.

It's a checkbox in post parameters called 'Encode?'

http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request